# While using a boolean method, how do I add the String contents of a txt file into an array list

Tags: java

I am attempting to use the method "public boolean readArtists" with a scanner to read strings from a file and return true if opened successfully. This method is also supposed to "Adds to the list all of the artists stored in the file passed parameter."

I've seen how to write the code in a public static void method that will read the text file and return it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("artists30.txt");

    String content = null;
    try {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
            content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Here is the test:

I have to keep the method "public boolean readArtists(String filename), so my question is, within this method, how do I read the contents of the text file into an ArrayList using a scanner, while also returning true if the file is opened successfully, Otherwise, handling the exception, displaying an appropriate error message containing the name of the missing file and return false.

Comment: when you say opened successfully do you mean to return true if the file exists and false if it does not?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Artists{
public static ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(readArtists("filename goes here"));
    System.out.println(artists);
}
public Artists(String artist, String genre)
{
}
public static boolean readArtists(String fileName) {
    
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("err "+fileName);
            return false;
        }
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            artists.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(sc!=null) {sc.close();}
    return true;
}
}
```

This answer reads data from a .txt document into an ArrayList, as long as the .txt document names are on seperate lines in the document. It also outputs `err \FILE\NAME` and returns false if the document does not exist and true if it does. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files.asp is a great website to learn java by the way and this link brings you to the file handling page.

Comment: this works as long as your .txt file is formatted correctly(ie. every name is on its own line and not in one continuous line), you could modify it to support other formats, however I find it is easier to copy names from websites into .txt files this way

Comment: oh and `artists` is a global variable

Comment: I just updated it, should support the artists variable now

Comment: just input your file name where it says `file name goes here` @ChocolateGoosePoosey

Comment: Never seen this error message: "Note: Artists.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

Comment: Actually, it's compiling but returning false. I replaced "filename goes here" with "artists30.txt"

Comment: you may have to use the full file name like `C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\artists30.txt`  unless you are storing the .txt file in the same folder as your .java program. This is for windows by the way if you are using mac or linux youll have to do the full file name

Comment: I'm on windows 10, using Jgrasp. The file is in the same folder as the artists.java file

Comment: Cancel that. It was just a misspelling. Working fine now

Comment: Great, Im glad it worked, make sure if it worked for you that you mark the answer as answered, thanks!

Comment: One more question. What if I wanted to split the artist and genre? For example. I'd like to count the total number of artists or the total number of artists of a particular genre. The format for the current list is something like: 

abba rock
Beethoven classical

Comment: You should look into the Scanner class from java.util, there are methods to split a line by white space so you could put words into another `ArrayList<String> genre`. A good link to the scanner class is https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp and for ArrayList https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

Comment: Didnt see anything about splitting in those links :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\testFile.txt";
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if(readArtists(filepath)) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            sc.useDelimiter("\\A"); 
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                arrayList.add(sc.next());
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
    
    public static boolean readArtists(String filename)
    {
       File file = new File(filename); //full path of the file with name
       return file.canRead();
    }
```

Comment: I see. But how do I put the contents of that file into an array list?

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey I've updated the code, pls take a look into it.